# (N^2) x (N^2) covariance matrix for an NxN matrix?

Tags: covariance, covariance-matrix, matrix

In a given process, it is mentioned that we need to obtain a (N^2) x (N^2) covariance matrix given a NxN matrix. Since we need to have multiple sets of observations to calculate a covariance, how can this be possible?

Edit: Suppose a matrix X is generated from a multivariate normal with a mean of 0 and a given variance. The covariance structure of this generated matrix (which is somehow supposed to be (N^2) x (N^2)) is to be used as the column covariance for generating another matrix Y which will have (N^2) columns.

Comment: more details of the situation will be needed

Comment: @Glen_b-ReinstateMonica Suppose it's a NxN image. The covariance matrix required is hence,               
![\sigma_p](https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=foo%2bbar) which, as it turns out is a (N^2) x (N^2) matrix. I was thinking maybe it's pixel wise covariance (covariance of each pixel with every other pixel) but I am not sure if that would make any sense.

Comment: Still not enough information. Do you have only one observation per pixel or more than one? Do you have a model that would imply a covariance structure (perhaps up to some small number of parameters to be estimated)?

Comment: @Glen_b-ReinstateMonica I have just one observation per pixel. I need to use the (N^2) x (N^2) covariance matrix of this image as the column covariance for generating a new matrix. Basically, the covariance structure of this image would form the column covariance of the new matrix. The new matrix (to be generated) will be having (N^2) columns.

Comment: 1. Any relevant information needs to be in the question, not in comments. 2. There still doesn't appear to be enough information here (e.g. about some model that would imply a covariance structure) to say anything relevant.

Comment: @Glen_b-ReinstateMonica Sorry about that, I am new here. Have updated the question.

Comment: What do you mean by "column covariance", and what exactly is your "a given process"? Please use conventional terms to describe your question. I suspect that you are using Gaussian Process to model the relationship between the pixels, if so, please spend some time reading the GP basics before jumping so fast to a practical question.

Comment: @HaotianChen By column covariance I mean the covariance between the columns of the matrix. It it's a 10x10 matrix, that would mean the covariance between the 10 columns (each having 10 observations).

Answer (score 2):

Referring the "covariance of the covariance matrix" implies the entries in the original $N\times N$ covariance matrix $S$ must be *estimates* of central second moments derived from some dataset "generated from a multivariate Normal" distribution $F.$

There are many ways to construct such estimates.  They depend on what you assume about $F$ and how much data you have.  What is common to the estimates in most frequent use is that they are based on the first two *empirical moments* of the data.  To describe this more clearly, let the data $x_{ij}$ consist of $m$ realizations of a random variable $X$ with $N$ components $(X_1, \ldots, X_N),$ so that for each $1\le i\le m,$ $\mathrm{x}_i = (x_{i1}, \ldots, x_{iN})$ constitutes one independent realization of $X.$  The first two empirical moments are

$$\mu^{(1)}_j = \mu^{(1)}_j(\mathrm{x}_1, \ldots, \mathrm{x}_m) =\frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m x_{ij}\tag{1}$$

and

$$\mu^{(2)}_{jk} =\mu^{(2)}_{jk}(\mathrm{x}_1, \ldots, \mathrm{x}_m) = \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m x_{ij} x_{ik}\tag{2}$$

for all $1\le j,k\le N.$  The *estimated covariance* between $X_j$ and $X_k$ is then given by some linear combination of these moments.  For example, the standard unbiased unweighted estimator is

$$(S^2)_{jk} = \frac{m}{m-1} \mu_{jk}^{(2)} - \frac{m}{m-1}\mu_j^{(1)}\mu_k^{(1)}.$$

For a general linear combination of such terms let's write

$$(S^2)_{jk} = \sum_{j^\prime k^\prime} \omega_{jk, j^\prime k^\prime}\,\mu_{j^\prime k^\prime}^{(2)} + \eta_{jk, j^\prime k^\prime}\,\mu_{j^\prime}^{(1)} \mu_{k^\prime}^{(1)}.\tag{3}$$

*The (constant) tensors $\omega_{jkj^\prime k^\prime}$ and $\eta_{jk, j^\prime k^\prime}$ determine the estimator $S^2.$*

To understand how such an estimator might vary from one sample to another, we can view the $\mathrm{x}_i$ as *random variables* rather than data.  Each of them has $F$ for its distribution and they are independent.  Given any two entries of an estimator $S^2(\mathrm{x}_1, \ldots, \mathrm{x}_m),$ say those with subscripts $(j,k)$ and $(j^\prime,k^\prime),$ we may thereby inquire about their covariance,

$$\operatorname{Cov}\left(S^2_{jk}, S^2_{j^\prime k^\prime}\right) = \mathbb{E}\left[\left(S^2_{jk} - \mathbb{E}\left[S^2_{jk}\right]\right) \left(S^2_{j^\prime k^\prime} - \mathbb{E}\left[S^2_{j^\prime k^\prime}\right]\right)\right].\tag{*}$$

Upon expanding the expression on the right hand side using $(1) - (3)$ above you reduce it to a linear combination of expectations of the form $E[x_{ij}\cdots x_{i^\prime j^\prime}]$ where four $x_{**}$ appear: each of these is a multivariate moment of degree $4.$  *All those moments can be expressed in terms of the parameters of the distribution $F.$*  When $F$ is multivariate Normal, those parameters can be taken to be its (vector) mean and its covariance matrix.

Depending on the details of the estimator $S^2$ and restrictions on those parameters, $(*)$ may simplify, but in general it's messy to write down.  I will therefore stop here, having shown what the meaning of the covariance of $S^2$ is and how it is possible to evaluate it in terms of properties of the underlying distribution $F.$